# Nested Dict with get command

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get a value from a nested dict in python. The problem is that when the parent of the nested dict is not available then I would like it to return a None or Zero but I guess the problem with my using the get is returning a Nonetype already and hence I am getting an error when I use:

```
pl_map.get(item)["ref_rate"]
```

Now the code works fine when item is available in the dict but it raises a TypeError as NoneType object is unsubscriptable.

Can any one please let me know how to resolve this problem, I have already pasted certain parts of the code below.

Basically pl_map is a nested dict as seen from the function below. I apologies for any kind of omissions I might have made.

```
for item in sorted(iwb_map):
    for wh in sorted(iwb_map[item]):
        #webnotes.msgprint(pl_map.get(item,0))
        qty_dict = iwb_map[item][wh]
        data.append([item,item_map[item]["description"], wh,
            qty_dict.bal_qty,pl_map.get(item)["ref_rate"],0,0,item_map[item]["base_material"],
            item_map[item]["quality"], item_map[item]["tool_type"], 
            item_map[item]["height_dia"], item_map[item]["width"],
            item_map[item]["length"], item_map[item]["d1"],
            item_map[item]["l1"], item_map[item]["is_rm"],
            item_map[item]["brand"]

        ])

def get_pl_map(filters):
    if filters.get("pl"):
        conditions = " and price_list_name = '%s'" % filters["pl"]
    else:
        webnotes.msgprint("Please select a Price List for Valuation Purposes", raise_exception=1)

    pl_map_int = webnotes.conn.sql ("""SELECT it.name, p.price_list_name, p.ref_rate
        FROM `tabItem` it, `tabItem Price` p
        WHERE p.parent = it.name %s
        ORDER BY it.name""" % conditions, as_dict=1)
    pl_map={}

    for d in pl_map_int:
        pl_map.setdefault(d.name,d)
    #webnotes.msgprint(pl_map)
    return pl_map
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have the first `.get()` return a empty dictionary as the default, then use `.get()` on that:

```
pl_map.get(item, {}).get("ref_rate")
```

Now you'll either get the value for `pl_map[item]['ref_rate']`, or `None`.

The alternative is to test for `item` explicitly:

```
pl_map[item]['ref_rate'] if item in pl_map else None
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to use a `defaultdict` so each not existing key is automatically initialized on first access:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> pl_map = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: None))
>>> pl_map["item"]["ref_rate"]    # returns None
```

After that all accessed keys will exist:

```
>>> pl_map
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x40350af0>, {'item': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x40350a30>, {'ref_rate': None})})
```